# Reaproveitar componente Angular 8, alterando a estrutura do json

Tags: json, angular, typescript, filter

Eu estou com 2 json parecidos, no entanto, com uma constante a mais em um deles. Eu gostaria de igualar os 2 para que eu possa reutilizar o mesmo componente e na mesma chamada.

Ex.:

```
"data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "titulo": "novaaaa",
            "thumbnail": null,
            "resumo": null,
            "autor": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "teste"
            },
            "tags": [],
            ...
        }]
```

```
"data": [
        {
        "receitas": {
            {
                "id": 1,
                "titulo": "novaaaa",
                "thumbnail": null,
                "resumo": null,
                "autor": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "teste"
                },
                "tags": [],
                ...

            }
          }]
```

A chamada dele está assim hoje:

```
 this.service.getAll(type, id_type, '', this.page).subscribe(res => {

         this.content = res.data.data;
}...
```

Qual é a melhor maneira e prática para eu igualar os 2 json e usa-lo no this.content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho bem estranho isso do retorno da Api ter estrutura de dados diferentes, acho que isso não deveria ser assim, mas, no seu caso é possível fazer o que quer com um simples **if/else** verificando se o retorno tem a propriedade **`receitas`** ou não através do método Javascript **[hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty)**:

```
this.service.getAll(type, id_type, '', this.page).subscribe(res => {
   if(res.data.data[0].hasOwnProperty('receitas')) {
     this.content = res.data.data[0]['receitas'];      // content com receitas
   } else this.content = res.data.data[0];             // content sem receitas
}
```

**OBS 1**: Quando vc diz **constante a mais**, na verdade é um **propriedade** a mais.

**OBS 2**: Seu segundo exemplo do retorno da api está errado, tem 2 **chaves - {{** uma após a outra, depois de receitas, e isso caracteriza um JSON com um formato inválido.

**OBS 3**: Não sei se tem o acesso a Api, mas tente mudar os nomes das propriedades, pois como pode ver **data.data** ficou redundante.

> Poder ver um exemplo do resultado funcionando [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/properties-stack).

Comment: Olá, muito obrigado pela resposta. Sobre a observação 1 e 3, o retorno vem do padrão paginate do laravel que está fazendo o backend. Sobre o item 2, na verdade eu só peguei um trecho do retorno da api. Por isso, pareceu um pouco incompleto. No exemplo que vc fez, ele está considerando a primeira posição da array, Mas usando hasOwnProperty(), atende também em um loop? Obrigado novamente.

Comment: Sim atende dentro de um loop normalmente, como um forEach() ou map() por exemplo.

Comment: Consegui, muito obrigado! Obs.: no loop ficou assim:
        this.content.map( function( elem ) {
          if(elem.hasOwnProperty('receitas')) {
           return elem['receitas'];
          } 
          return elem;
        });

Comment: Boa Rubens isso mesmo, sucesso aí!